# Is there a way I can fix this error without re-adding the device to the domain

Tags: powershell, appx, comexception

When running the command "Get-Appxpackage -AllUsers" it errors on about 3% of the devices I deploy it to. So far this is around 30 in 900. It does not error if you do not have "-Allusers" parameter present. I have included the error below. I am aware of the normal fixes for trust relationship errors and I have tried the following:

- Resetting the local machine password as suggested when you search how to fix trust relationship error
- Running Test-ComputerSecureChannel comes back true.
- Running nltest /sc_verify:EXAMPLEDOMAIN shows the trust is verified.
- I have tried running "Get-Appxpackage -User 'example.user'" and it does not serve the function I need.
- I have tried wsreset.exe

The error message is not the standard workstation to primary domain message. It is the primary domain to the trusted domain. As far as I am aware this is normally only on servers that have this but this is showing on workstations. Please see the highlighted differences below.

Get-Appxpackage -AllUsers
Get-Appxpackage : The trust relationship between the **primary domain and the trusted domain** failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706FC)
At line:1 char:1

- Get-Appxpackage -AllUsers
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AppxPackage], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.GetAppxPackageCommand
  ```

If I remove and re-add the device to the domain it does fix the issue. However this is not practical. I would like to know what re-adding the device to domain is doing to fix this so that I can fix it remotely via script.